# ES6: How to compare values in two arrays

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have two arrays;

```
let items = {
    search: [
       ['car', 'door', 'pen']
    ]
}

let data.props = [];

data.props = [
    {label: "car"}, 
    {label: "window"},
    {label: "kettle"},
    {label: "chair"},
    {label: "door"},
]
```

How can I check/compare between the two arrays using es6? A little bit tricky for me since `items[]` is a nested array.

What I have only checks for the first item.

```
if (data.props['0'].label === items.search['0'].values['0']) {
        let searchItems = [];
        searchItems.push(data.props['0']);
        console.log(searchItems);
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "check/compare between the two arrays"? Please provide desired output and show your attempt to implement the requirement.

Comment: what are you aiming for?

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: Your code is invalid JS. You cannot assign to data.props without having an object first and you should not quote array indicii

Comment: Your code is not more valid now after your edit. Please read up on array vs objects. `search: [
        values: ['car', 'door', 'pen']
    ]` is not a valid array entry. Create a snippet using `<>` and test it to make a [mcve]

Comment: thanks for the feedback all. I was rushing while creating this question -  apologies for the edits here and there. I think I have the insight I need to solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use streams:

```js
// if multiple search values:
const items = {
    search: {
        values: ['car', 'door', 'pen']
    }
}

let data = {
  props: []
};

data.props = [
    {label: "window"}, 
    {label: "car"},
    {label: "kettle"},
    {label: "chair"},
    {label: "door"},
];

let matches = data.props
  .map(prop => prop.label)
  .filter(prop => items.search.values.indexOf(prop) >= 0);
  
console.log(matches);

// if one search value

let searchItem = "car";

matches = data.props
  .map(prop => prop.label)
  .filter(prop => searchItem === prop);
  
console.log(matches);
```

Comment: Search is an array with one value. Someone edited my question wrongly

Comment: As long as it's an array, it should still work.

Comment: I added an answer for one item as well :)

Comment: Interesting.. I get a red line under `indexOf`. remember `search` is `[]` not  `{}`.. typescript error though. but that should point me in the right direction thanks.

Comment: Search should not be a [] unless it is `search: ['car', 'door', 'pen']`

Comment: In your example `search` is actually an object (so `{}`) and `search.value` is an array (`[]`)

Answer (score 0):

```
let items = {
    search: {
        values: ['car', 'door', 'pen']
    }
}

let data = {
  props: [
        {label: "window"}, 
        {label: "car"},
        {label: "kettle"},
        {label: "chair"},
        {label: "door"},
    ]
}

console.log(data.props.filter(prop => items.search.values.indexOf(prop.label) >= 0));
```

log output is :

```
[0]: {label: "car"}
[1]: {label: "door"}
```

Comment: Why filter twice: `data.props.filter(prop => items.search.values.indexOf(prop.label) >= 0)`